# How can I connect to my NAS that has a static IP that uses the wrong gateway address?

Tags: router, nas, static-ip

I have a nas that for reasons I set up to use a static IP. One ISP switch later and now I can't access my NAS, because it uses the wrong default gateway address. I can therefore also not access the settings on that nas to change that default gateway.

I do however see the ARP broadcast messages from that NAS with wireshark on my pc. Is there a way for me to get access to my NAS without wiping the data?

I thought to maybe setup a (virtual) router on my pc with that listens to the correct gateway address, but solutions I found only have OS images to create a router like that or virtual routers that only work for wifi, where I need a router on my ethernet connection. Any tips regarding this or any other way to fix this issue?

Router specs:
Ziggo ConnectBox 10.

**Edit:**

My NAS is trying to connect reach the gateway on `192.168.2.254`. My router is currently on `192.168.178.1`. While I can change the `178`, the ConnectBox router doesn't allow you to change the `1` (see: [link](https://translate.google.nl/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.ziggo.nl%2Fthuisnetwerk-software-101%2Fconnectbox-lan-ip-adres-niet-helemaal-aanpasbaar-43961)), so I can't just change my router to the old gateway address and be done with it.

Comment: If you know the static IP address of the NAS it's that simple: change your PC's IP address to the old IP network and you get immediately the connection to the NAS. Change the NAS IP configuration and restore your PC's configuration. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to do it by following this guide: [link](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/connect-synology-nas-directly-to-pc-without-router-external-dhcp.html). It basically helps you setup a local DHCP server [link](https://www.dhcpserver.de/cms/download/).

Additionally to the steps in the article I edited the ini file (mentioned in the article) to use the correct gateway address (`192.168.2.254` in my case) and also set my ethernet adapter of my PC to use that IP address.

After that I was able to access my NAS, so I could update the static IP configuration to use my router as gateway. Finally I had to restore my old ethernet adapter settings on my PC, so that it had internet access again. After this, I could access my NAS through the subnet of my router.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you changed ISP you also changed the router, which changed
the allocated IP address range.

Let's say that the old range was `192.168.0.x` and the new is `192.168.1.x`.

Just set the new router to use the old range of `192.168.0.x` and ensure
that the router allocates to itself the old address.
In this example, the router's IP would probably be `192.168.0.1`.

You local network should now work as before.

Comment: I thought of that, but there is one small problem. The new router is indeed on 192.168.x.1, but my old router's ip was 192.168.y.254 and I don't see an option to change my router's IP address to that address.

Comment: Do you have a link to an English version of your router's manual?

Comment: This is a manual from a different internet provider, and some things are different like the default gateway IP, but the rest seems to be the same: https://www.manualslib.com/download/1075950/Upc-Cablecom-Connect-Box.html

Comment: Ok I found on Ziggo's community forum that with a gateway IP of 192.168.x.y, I can change the x, but I'm unable to change the y. See here (translated with google): https://translate.google.nl/translate?sl=nl&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fcommunity.ziggo.nl%2Fthuisnetwerk-software-101%2Fconnectbox-lan-ip-adres-niet-helemaal-aanpasbaar-43961